# How do I design a couchdb view for following case ?

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I am migrating an application from mySQL to couchDB. (Okay, Please dont pass judgements on this).

There is a function with signature

```
getUserBy($column, $value)
```

Now you can see that in case of SQL it is a trivial job to construct a query and fire it.

However as far as couchDB is concerned I am supposed to write views with map functions

Currently I have many views such as

```
get_user_by_name
get_user_by_email
```

and so on. Can anyone suggest a better and yet scalable way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! One of my favorite views, for its power, is `by_field`. It's a pretty simple map function.

```
function(doc) {
    // by_field: map function
    // A single view for every field in every document!
    var field, key;

    for (field in doc) {
        key = [field, doc[field]];
        emit(key, 1);
    }
}
```

Suppose your documents have a `.name` field for their name, and `.email` for their email address.

To get users by name (ex. "Alice" and "Bob"):

```
GET /db/_design/example/_view/by_field?include_docs=true&key=["name","Alice"]
GET /db/_design/example/_view/by_field?include_docs=true&key=["name","Bob"]
```

To get users by email, from the same view:

```
GET /db/_design/example/_view/by_field?include_docs=true&key=["email","alice@gmail.com"]
GET /db/_design/example/_view/by_field?include_docs=true&key=["name","bob@gmail.com"]
```

The reason I like to emit `1` is so you can write reduce functions later to use `sum()` to easily add up the documents that match your query.

Comment: That is how I solved this problem but my concern was scalability. For n documents with m fields each it is outputting approximately n*m rows. I am not familiar with the internals of CouchDB but being a mysql guy I wonder if that is going to take up a very long time.

Comment: It may take some time when the view is initially called, but view results are cached, so only updated documents are considered when querying the view again.

Comment: Also, if you don't need every field output, you can modify the "by_field" MapReduce above to output only the fields you are (or plan to be) interested in. In your n*m equation, m would be the number of fields you care about. That said, leaving it "wide open" does give you more flexibility, but at the cost (though relatively minimal) of more disk space used by the view's index (the results cache that gre mentioned).